# Copy/Paste Text from Rich-Text Box to Facebook

Tags: vb.net, richtextbox

I am writing a Wordle type program in Visual Basic and I am having an issue with the Share portion after you win the game.  I have a "Share" button you can click on to post your win to Facebook if you want.  I created a hidden Rich-Text box to build the post, then I copy it to the clipboard for the user.  All they have to do is paste it into Facebook.  It won't paste in Facebook, but when I try pasting to MS-Word, it works fine.  I could use some assistance!

```
Private Sub btnShare_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnShare.Click
        Dim Header As Integer, i As Integer, j As Integer
        Dim SetBox As String    'Var to define the current Textbox name

        'Set SHARE Header Text and define Header as the length of the Header
        rtbGame.Text = "Verdle #" & WODNumber & " " & FinalRow & "/6" & vbCrLf
        Header = rtbGame.Text.Length - 1

        'Begin extraction of the Player's Textbox Guesses for the 'Sharing' message to be generated.
        '** Used for posting to social media
        For i = 1 To FinalRow
            For j = 1 To 5
                'Select played textboxes one by one
                SetBox = "txt" & CStr(i) & CStr(j)
                Select Case CType(frmVerdle.Controls(SetBox), TextBox).BackColor.ToString
                    Case Green.ToString, DMGreen.ToString, HiGreen.ToString
                        rtbGame.AppendText(rtbSample.Text.Substring(1, 1).ToUpper)
                        rtbGame.SelectionStart = Header + j
                        rtbGame.SelectionLength = 1
                        rtbGame.SelectionColor = Green
                    Case Amber.ToString, DMAmber.ToString, HiAmber.ToString
                        rtbGame.AppendText(rtbSample.Text.Substring(1, 1).ToUpper)
                        rtbGame.SelectionStart = Header + j
                        rtbGame.SelectionLength = 1
                        rtbGame.SelectionColor = Amber
                    Case DMGGray.ToString, LMGGray.ToString
                        rtbGame.AppendText(rtbSample.Text.Substring(1, 1).ToUpper)
                        rtbGame.SelectionStart = Header + j
                        rtbGame.SelectionLength = 1
                        rtbGame.SelectionColor = LMGGray
                End Select
            Next
            Header += 6
            rtbGame.SelectionLength = 0
            If i <> FinalRow Then
                rtbGame.AppendText(vbCrLf)
            End If
        Next
        ' Copy the string to the clipboard
        Clipboard.SetText(rtbGame.Text, TextDataFormat.Rtf)   ' I also tried .HTML

        MessageBox.Show("Your Game details were copied to the Clipboard.", "Game Statistics", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
    End Sub
```

This is what the Rich-Text Box looks like once a "post" is created.   Normally the form is not as wide and the 2 fields are hidden.

[image]

I would like to understand how to format my text so it can be posted to Facebook.

Comment: I don't know how Facebook posts because I haven't used it, but can I give you some help with clipboard-related formatting instructions

Comment: Thanks - I was able to figure it out.  I had to use a certain font with specific characters.  I have no idea 'why" it works, but for my purposes, it does in this case!